# Passing result from one helper function to another

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, helper

I am trying to get the org domain in a lightning comp and use that to redirect to the QLE of a record. For some reason, I am receiving undefined on my helper fucntion that calls a nother helper function, which gets the org domain from the apex controller. Can someone point why I am getting this issue? Here are snippets of my code.

//Apex Controller

```
@AuraEnabled   
    public static string getDomain(){   
        String url = String.valueof(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().gethost());
        String url2 = urlInstance.removeEndIgnoreCase('.my.salesforce.com');
        return url2;
    }
```

//Helper.Js

```
fetchDom: function(component, event, helper, result) {

    var orgDom = component.get("c.getDomain");
    console.log('orgDom: ', orgDom ); **//THIS IS GETTING RESULT**

    orgDom.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var result = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log('result: ' +  result);
        return result;
    });
},
rediRectToUrl: function (component, event, helper, result) {
    let recordId = result;
    var myDomain = this.fetchDom(component, event, helper, result);
    console.log('myDom:', myDom); **//THIS IS GETTING UNDEFINED**

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": 'https://' + myDomain + '--sbqq.visualforce.com/apex/sb?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + recordId + '#quote/le?qId=' + recordId
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call $A.enqueueAction, so the server was never called. In addition, server calls are asynchronous, so you need to wait for the result. We do this with a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In addition, you called the variable `myDom` at one point, and `myDomain` at the other.

```
  fetchDom(component) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const orgDom = component.get('c.getDomain')
      orgDom.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        const status = response.getState()
        if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
          resolve(response.getReturnValue())
        }
        if (status === 'ERROR') {
          reject(response.getError())
        }
      })
      $A.enqueueAction(orgDom)
    })
  },
  rediRectToUrl(component, event, helper, result) {
    const recordId = result
    this.fetchDom(component).then((myDomain) => {
      console.log('myDomain:', myDomain)
      const urlEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL')
      urlEvent.setParams({
        url: `https://${myDomain}--sbqq.visualforce.com/apex/sb?scontrolCaching=1&id=${recordId}#quote/le?qId=${recordId}`,
      })
      urlEvent.fire()
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox Thanks for answering! I tried your code but I wasn't redirected to the QLE. I noticed on my logs that It is entering the rediRectToUrl function but not even entering this part console.log('myDomain:', myDomain) within the same function. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Charlie Are you getting any errors? Try adding a console.log inside the callback to see what the state and return values are, or if you're getting an error.

Comment: Yes I added console logs on the setcallback of fetchDom to see the the state it is entering but the logs aren't showing up. It seems like it is not even entering the fetchDom function. I have a console log as well before the "this.fetchDom(component).then((myDomain) => {" line on rediRectToUrl function, and that is showing up. The logs after that line however, don't.

Comment: @Charlie Fair enough. One sec, I'll reproduce in my org so I can troubleshoot.

Comment: @Charlie typo was in my code. getStatus should have been getState. Give that a try.

Comment: that worked! Thanks very much!